# Why can't I create a notification channel in this fragment?

Tags: android, notifications, display, channel

I tried to create a notification channel in my fragment but it doesn't seem to work. I am trying to make a floating action button which, once pressed will send a notification which will only display text and nothing else. The notification doesn't need to link to any activity at the moment. However, when is tried to create a notification channel under this fragment, it will highlight out:

```
NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
```

as red, saying it can't resolve method getSystemService().

This is my code:

```
public class NotificationsFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false);
    //Notification channel creator
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("test", "TestName", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("description");
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    FloatingActionButton actionButton = v.findViewById(R.id.notifications_floatingActionButton);
    actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Write code here to execute after floating action button has been clicked:
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), NotificationsEditor.class)); // starts notification editor - this is also template for starting activity in fragment
            displayNotifications();//part of notifications
        }
    });
    return v;
}

//part of notification
public void displayNotifications(){
    String ID = "notifications";
    NotificationCompat.Builder notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.requireContext(), ID);
    notif.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications);
    notif.setContentTitle("Notification");
    notif.setContentText("Notification Example");
    notif.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    NotificationManagerCompat display = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this.requireContext());
    display.notify(1, notif.build());

}//ends here
```

}

I have tried to create a method for the notification channel in the MainActivity and still failed as the notification would not show up during runtime and I have also tried to create a method for the notification channel as a method in this class and it still failed at runtime to display the notification. I am very new to android studio and app development so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`getSystemService` is a method on `Context`, so you need to use `requireContext()` to get a `Context`, and call `getSystemService()` on that.

```
NotificationManager manager = requireContext().getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
```

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't work at runtime as it shows up "failed to post notifications on channel "notifications" as a toast message when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out whats wrong! On top of adding the context to `getSystemService()` I also needed to make sure that the channel ID was the same for the code to build the notification as well as the code to build the notification channel.